# Create partition for MacOS installation

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I was playing around with Asahi Linux and want to reinstall MacOS in the whole disk again. I ended up deleting all volumes/partitions (not sure what term is correct here). How I have access to recovery but in the option to reinstall MacOS no volume candidate appears for installation. Here's what diskutil list looks like
[image]

As you can see there is free space (494GB) but I couldn't figure out the commands to set up this space for the new OS install.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: These steps will erase disk0 and get you back on track… https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-and-reinstall-macos-mh27903/mac You’ve got all the things you need showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, one command:

```
diskutil addpartition disk0s1 apfs macOS 0
```

After this command, the 494GB APFS Volume should pop up in the Disk Utility.